# python change namespace across modules?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have created a module named `my_mod`, and within it there are two files `__init__.py` and `my_func.py`:
**__init__.py**:

```py
import numpy
import cupy

xp = numpy # xp defaults to numpy

# a decorator that change `xp` based on input array class
def array_dispatch(fcn):
    def wrapper(x, *args, **kwargs):
        global xp
        xp = cupy if isinstance(x, cupy.ndarray) else numpy
        return fcn(x, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

from .my_func import *
```

and **my_func.py**:

```py
from my_mod import xp, array_dispatch

@array_dispatch
def print_xp(x):
    print(xp.__name__)
```

basically I'd like `print_xp` to print out either "numpy" or "cupy" based on the class of the input `x`: if the input `x` to `print_xp` is a numpy array, then print out "numpy"; if `x` is a cupy array, then it should print out "cupy".

However, currently it always prints out "numpy", which is the default of `xp`. Can someone help me understand why, and what is the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question, don't do:

```
from my_mod import xp, array_dispatch
```

Instead, use

```
import my_mod
```

then refer to `my_mod.xp` in your function:

```
@my_mod.array_dispatch
def print_xp(x):
    print(my_mod.xp.__name__)
```

Then you'll see the updates to `my_mod`'s global namespace...

Although, you really should try to avoid using a global variable like this at all.

EDIT: Here's an approach I would take, if I understand what you want correctly.

```
import inspect
import cupy
import numpy

def array_dispatch(fcn):
    sig = inspect.signature(fcn)
    param = sig.parameters.get("xp")
    if param is None:
        raise ValueError("function must have an `xp` paramter")
    if param.kind is not inspect.Parameter.KEYWORD_ONLY:
        raise ValueError(f"`xp` parameter must be keyword only, got {param.kind}")
    
    def wrapper(x, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(x, cupy.ndarray):
            xp = cupy
        elif isinstance(x, numpy.ndarray):
            xp = numpy
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"expected either a numpy.ndarray or a cupy.ndarray, got {type(x)}")
        return fcn(x, *args, xp=xp, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then, an example user of this decorator:

from my_mod import xp, array_dispatch

```
@array_dispatch
def frobnicate(x, *, xp):
    return xp.tanh(x) + 42


import numpy as np

print(frobnicate(np.arange(10)))
```

Comment: Thanks it works! May I ask why everyone suggests avoid using global variables? from my understanding this may pollute the name space, is that all? what if I take extra care and not create any variable named `xp`, will this be absolutely safe?

Comment: @Sam-gege using *mutable* global state leads to hard to reason about programs and "spaghetti code". It is a classic anti-pattern. For very small programs it doesn't matter (not much really does for *small* programs) but as soon as things become even a little complex it becomes a problem

Comment: what do you think is a good practice for my case? I need to choose numpy.tanh or cupy.tanh based on whether the input is numpy array or cupy array. Thanks!!

Comment: One simple thing here is to define your functions to take `xp` as an argument, perhaps a keyword-only argument,. The your in your decorator, in the wrapper, you do `xp = cupy if isinstance(x, cupy.ndarray) else numpy` then `fcn(x, *args, xp=xp, **kwargs)`

Comment: @Sam-gege see my edit for an example, I would also probably explicitly check if it is an instance of both numpy.ndarray and cupy.ndarray, and raise a `TypeError` if it is neither.

Comment: good idea... Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Define `xp` as an array

```
import numpy
import cupy

xp = [numpy] # xp defaults to numpy

# a decorator that change `xp` based on input array class
def array_dispatch(fcn):
    def wrapper(x, *args, **kwargs):
        global xp
        xp[0] = cupy if isinstance(x, cupy.ndarray) else numpy
        return fcn(x, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

from .my_func import *
```

and

```py
from my_mod import xp, array_dispatch

@array_dispatch
def print_xp(x):
    print(xp[0].__name__)
```